# Do I also add half my level again if I can add a second attribute to a roll?

Tags: dnd-4e, initiative

Consider a level 4 character with 14 Dex and 16 Int. Normally this character would have an initiative modifier of +4; +2 for Dex, and +2 for half level. If this character takes a feat or gains a magic item that allows them to also add their Int mod to their initiative modifier, do they also get to add half their level a 2nd time?

That is, should the character's initiative modifier now be
`+2(Dex) +2(lvl) +3(Int)         = +7`
or should it be
`+2(Dex) +2(lvl) +3(int) +2(lvl) = +9`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, you only ever add half your level to a roll once.**

The rules explicitly say to add half your level to attack rolls, skill checks, and ability checks, as described on page 67 of the PHB. Per page 267 of the PHB, initiative is an ability check (specifically, it is a Dexterity check).

Those rules are (nearly) the *only* places you're told to add half your level. Unless the feat or item in question explicitly tells you to add half your level in addition to an attribute modifier (such as your Int mod), you only the attribute modifier.